# Using selenium to test AngularJs, Can I access ng-csv

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, selenium

I am writing a test and I want to use some data that Angularjs generates for a download instead of downloading the file if possible. I have tried pulling the data from the site but data is pulled and dropped as you scroll through the site making it hard to write tests that are reliable. I have posted the html that generates the download event. I know the function to generate the data is getFilterList(), I just do not know how to use selenium to get the data.

```
<button ng-csv="getFilteredList()" filename="providers.csv" ng-disabled="!grid.numFiltered" lazy-load="true" csv-header="getCsvHeaders()" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link right ng-isolate-scope" ng-click=""> 
    Export Filtered List
</button>
```

Also, I have to use selenium because there is already a framework that everyone uses.

Comment: Since this is an `angularjs` app, you are probably using `protractor`?

Comment: I cannot, I have to use Java and selenium. Protractor would probably be the better choice though.

Comment: Ok, just to clarify, when you click the button, there is a download popup appearing asking you to save the csv file, right? This is something you need to automate with selenium?

Comment: I can do that, but I was hoping to somehow call the getFilteredList() function through selenium because that would be easier if it is possible.